# getContentResolver().query() throws NullPointException

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I wonder what can cause `NullPointException` in the following code?
The problem is that I don't get `NullPointException` not on my devices not on emulator, but in my google analytic I see tons of exception on the `query()` method line. So what can cause this? May be I need `new String[] {"*"}` as projetion instead of just `null`? Has anyone faced such a problem?

```
final String selection = THREAD_ID + "=" + threadId;

try{
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MmsSms.CONTENT_DRAFT_URI,
            null,
            selection,
            null,
            null);

} catch(Exception e){
    trackException(e);
}
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to tell that `context` here cannot be null because it is used in the method that calls this method, so if it was null I will get exception in the upper method. `context` is definitely not null.

Comment: NullPointException? Then post the Logcat... where it logs the actual Exception you are referring to...

Comment: @shkschneider , I cannot reproduce this exception on my devices, I only see it in my google analytics Exceptions report. I have tons of this exception in my analytics reports but in my devices I don't get it at all. It is something related to the specific roms of android I guess...

Comment: Well you *have to* reproduce the error to know what is going on. Same for us: it's hard to guess by looking at literally one line of code what is wrong...

Comment: @shkschneider, I understand, I just thought there might be some standard issue with ContentResolver that somebody had already faced. I think putting `new String[] {"*"}` instead of just null in projection might fix it. I just wanted to be sure before publishing an update to production..

Comment: Are you sure getContentResolver() is returning null?  Or perhaps is it the returned cursor that is null?

Comment: If it's really getContentResolver(), is it possible that you're calling getContentResolver() before the onCreate of a service?

Comment: @Buddy, I it is not a service and is not called from service. It is a static method that is being called from a fragment after onCreate, the context is actually the instance of the Application class (I have extended Application class). May be something is wrong with it that I use Application class as context?